# Update PickerView with new data if the view is already being shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am fetch data from the server to display in a picker view. If the API has not returned i display `Loading...` in the picker view.

Here is my use case:

1. API Call made to the server
2. User clicks button to show picker view.
3. Picker View is shown and displays the text LOADING...
4. API call returns. i call `[self.seasonEpiPickerView reloadAllComponents];`

Nothing happens. Basically since the picker view is already loaded and being shown on the screen it is not updating its data. How can i update the data of a picker view that is already being displayed?

Comment: you need to update your datasource before `-reloadAllComponents`

Comment: Solved it: My response from the server was not on the main thread. I had put a test thread to delay UI updates for testing. I removed the test code and executed the updateUI lines from the main thread and everything works with the same above code.

Comment: Good. You should post that as the answer, might help others who has the same issue.. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: My response from the server was not on the main thread. I had put a test thread to delay UI updates for testing. I removed the test code and executed the updateUI lines from the main thread and everything works with the same above code.

Answer (score 0):

You need

**In .h file**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>
```

**In .m file** set delegate and datasource

```
yourpicker.delegate = self;
yourpicker.datasource = self;
```

may this help you